# How can I emulate 4G (LTE) network in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, lte, 4g

Could you please help me, is it possible to emulate 4G (LTE) network in Android SDK? I need Android emulator with LTE network for testing. Or there is some other soft which can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the emulator can simulate the *speed* of an LTE network, i.e. you should be able to do one of the following:

1) Start the emulator with the following option:

```
emulator -netspeed lte <other-options>
```

2) Connect to an existing emulator's console (e.g. telnet localhost 5554), then type:

```
network speed lte
```

On the other hand, I don't think there is a way to simulate a real LTE network out of the emulator, if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: `network speed lte` does not work in telnet. Enter `help network speed` to get a list of valid options.

Comment: @Digit, thanks for code. It works for other networks like GSM, but not for LTE, terminal returns error - ko:invalid -netspeed parameter 'lte' which means LTE is not supported on the device. Could you please explain how we can get a virtual device with LTE support?